# Excel Sheet using Query

Tags: excel

I have 5 excel tabs Jan, Fab, March, Apr, and May. Each of these sheets has 9 columns which are; Name - Location ID - Description - On Hand-Left - Box/Pack-Date of Inventory - Min-Max - Comment.

Then I have the main tab which is called MasterSheet.

My question is, how can I write a query in the MasterSheet to pull 
Name - Location ID - Description - On Hand-Left-Box/Pack -Date of Inventory -Min - Max from the other tabs. With this condition: pull the data that has the number on hand less than 5.[This is how the tabs looks like. For example I only want Row3,5, and 6 to go to the Mastersheet because the number on hand is less than 5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8jax1.png)

Comment: Hi Luke, can you post some example data, and perhaps the code you've tried so far? Also there are several ways to go about this. Are you trying to do this with formula's or vba?

Comment: I added a picture and wrote some explanation on what I am trying to do. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

1. Merge/Append the queries together
2. Ensure the column you want to filter by is a number value type
3. Click the arrow and create a `Number Filter` for the value you want using the criteria you want.

Comment: I want the data on (Hand < 5) to go automatically to the masterSheet.

Comment: It will once you refresh the query